# Difference between main field and entry point field in package.json

Tags: package.json

What is the difference between the main field and the entry point field in package.json?

Using `npm init -y`, I get the main field.
Using `npm init` and taking defaults, I get the entry point field.

Is there any difference between the two?

Comment: what do you mean by having entry point in package.json? There is no such thing as a field in package.json, that is named `entryPoint`.
In the prompts being shown when running `npm init` you are asked for an entry point, that is correct. But the value passed to it will be written to field `main` in your package.json.

Comment: I only know of `main` and `exports`, and _these define the entry point of the package._

Comment: You can likely find your answer in the NPM docs. For example, [here's the entry on `main`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json#main).

Comment: @FabianStrathaus you have answered my question. Thanks!

Comment: you're welcome! I also added this as an actual answer. Feel free to accept it and close your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be complete, here is my answer:

There is no such thing as a field in package.json, that is named entryPoint. In the prompts being shown when running npm init you are asked for an entry point, that is correct. But the value passed to it will be written to field main in your package.json.